# Слетели DNS на виртуальной машине VMWare Ubuntu. Как настроить?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, vmware, виртуализация

Есть сервер в VMWare, до недавно времени на нем всё прекрасно работало, но сегодня что то пошло не так. Насколько я понимаю, слетели днс.
Пинг до локального шлюза - ок, пинг до 8.8.8.8 и 1.1.1.1 - ок, пинг до ya.ru и google.com не проходит. При этом на родительской машине всё ок и ничего не менялось. Она, кстати, на винде. 
Пробовал делать новую виртуальку, как десктоп, так и сервер - везде то же самое. Сеть в виртуалку отдаю по NATу. В чем может быть проблема? 
В сетевой карте родителя ставил и днс провайдера, и днс гугла. Не работает.

Comment: Как проявляется "не проходит"? Какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: ping: ya.ru: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Посмотрите `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` и `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: в resolve.conf добавил адрес dns сервера, но что то ничего.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options edns0
search localdomain